# Simplest way to get a public URL for a photo from Photos App?

Tags: photos

My phone already syncs photos to my laptop Photos App. I'm looking for the simplest way to share photos from the Photos App to the internet. I don't want albums or anything, just to get the URL of an individual photo. Ideally it happens automatically, and I just right click the photo in the Photos app and click "copy image url"

I tried using Imgur, but you can't even drag and drop photos from the app to the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click a picture in Photos, Share [More... if you don't see all the options]

Flickr has a built-in uploader option, but not Imgur.

[image]

There are some tools listed on [Imgur Help](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/209592766-Tools-for-Imgur), though I haven't tried any of them personally.

Otherwise the 'simplest' way to get pictures from Photos to Imgur is to drag from Photos to the Desktop, then from the Desktop to the Imgur page... [then throw away the one on the Desktop]

Alternatively, [Gyazo](https://gyazo.com/) has an app that will let you instantly upload & add a link to your clipboard.

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) allows you to right click & share a link to any file stored in it - though you'd have to follow the 'drag to Desktop [or Dropbox]' procedure as above, without then discarding the original.